# Расположение одного модального окна поверх другого

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Есть модальное окно поверх которого нужно вызвать ещё одно.
Так получается сделать если только вызывать модальные окна в разные контейнеры. А если в одни, то не получается, что бы второе окно вызвалось поверх первого.

Первое модальное окно:

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoStore.Domain.Core.Order>

<div id="Orders" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Список заказов</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Дата заказа</th>
                            <th>Марка автомобиля</th>
                            <th>Модель автомобиля</th>
                            <th>Цена</th>
                            <th>Клиент</th>
                            <th>Сотрудник</th>
                            <th>Статус заказа</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="orderInf">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            string clientFIO = item.Clients.CSurname + " " + item.Clients.CName + " " + item.Clients.CPatronymic;
                            string sellerFIO = item.Sellers == null ? "" : item.Sellers.SSurname + " " + item.Sellers.SName + " " + item.Sellers.SPatronymic;
                            <tr id="@item.Id">
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.OrderDate)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Cars.Equipment.CarModel.Mark.MarkName)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Cars.Equipment.CarModel.ModelName)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.TotalPrice)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => clientFIO)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => sellerFIO)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Status)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div id="equip"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnHideInf" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Скрыть информацию</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Второе модальное окно:

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoStore.Domain.Core.Seller>

    <div id="Sellers" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Список продавцов</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Сотрудник</th>
                                <th>Должность</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                string sellerFIO = item.SSurname + " " + item.SName + " " + item.SPatronymic;
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => sellerFIO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Position)</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="btnHideInf" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Скрыть информацию</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Вот место куда я их ложу.

```
<div id="modalMenu"></div>
```

Этот див распологается на мастер странице.

Вот как я ложу модальные окна в этот див:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Administration/_IssuedOrders",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#modalMenu').html(result);
                $('#Orders').modal('show');
            }
        })

$.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "/Administration/_SellersList",
                                success: function (result) {
                                    $('#modalSellers').html(result);
                                    $('#Sellers').modal('show');
                                }
                            });
```

Как сделать так что бы второе окно расположилось поверх первого?

Comment: $('#modalSellers').append(result);

Comment: Но придется отслеживать открыты ли окна, чтобы по два раза не открыть, и очищать контейнер $('#modalSellers').empty()

Comment: @Kain такой вариант мне не подходит, мне нужно что бы в одном контейнере было 2 окна открыты одновременно. И я так пробовал. Открыл одну модалку, потом туда же засунул вторую и открыл её, она открылась сзади первой.

Comment: полагаю, что у модалок в стилях position: absolute, и вам нужно проверить стиль z-index. Возможно, у одной модалки там значение, скажем 11, а у второй (открывающейся под ней) 10

Comment: @Kain да спасибо. В этом дело. Там у окна z-index 1050 из за этого и не получалось.